# Resize window parts in runtime

Tags: wpf, resize, window

I want to have main window split in three parts like the one on the picture. there's supposed to be a line (red one) or left border of the rectangle number 2, that, when it's dragged with mouse, it resizes both rectangle 1 and 2. it's like the behaviour of playlist in windows media player. any ideas on how to obtain this? Also, it would be great if someone proposes a solution to how this playlist make collapsed if the red line is dragged to the right.

[image: window in three parts]

Comment: There's something on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34377/DockPanel-Splitter-Control-for-WPF) that add spltters to the WPF DockPanel.

Comment: The common name for that is a splitter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a `<Grid>` with columns and rows like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="600"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
```

and then the gridsplitter (still inside the grid):

```
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ResizeDirection="Columns" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Note that the gridsplitter will need it's own column.

Comment: Ok, great, but I don't know how to put the content I already have in these cells created by column/row definitions? How to place my listbox in third column and first row?

Comment: <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>

Comment: When you place a control like a ListBox inside a Grid the listbox will get something called Attached Properties. In this case Grid.Row and Grid.Column, which you can use to place your content in the right row and column. It's zero-based.

Comment: @ahdaniels, great, working, thank you so much. is there a way to lock 3rd rectangle so it doesn't resize? I made sure the span is only 1 column and one row, but still it resizes bottom rectangle.

Comment: Set Grid.ColumnSpan="3" to the control placed in the rectangle

Answer (score 3):

It is a [GridSplitter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter.aspx), here is how to use one:

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" 
              Height="5" 
              Width="Auto" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Background="Gray" 
              ResizeDirection="Rows" />
```

You need to assign a `Row` or `Column` to it from your `Grid`, and specify its `ResizeDirection`. This one is horizontal, but you get the idea for a vertical one.

HTH,

Bab.

Comment: ok, i have those definitions, it resizes 1 and two, but also 3rd rectangle. is there any way i can lock the width of third rectangle?

Comment: Please show the XAML you're using. You're probably going to have to set the width of the third column to Auto or a fixed size.

Comment: thank you @ahdaniels, you've made me understand this technique. i set the column and row span, position and horizontal/vertical alignment, it works just as i wish.